CORS using AWS Apigateway with EC2
Hey there stackoverflow community, I am trying to setup an aws API Gateway that links to a nodeJS app running on EC2 instance, it works fine with postman or a direct url link, but won't work when the API is called from my reactjs app (using axios), even running locally.  I obviously enabled CORS as follow in my API Gateway and deployed it: 
I tried every answers given on stackoverflow, but most of them are using lambda, maybe I need to do something else for EC2?
What am I missing? is there something I need to add to my axios params maybe? it returns a 200 non the less however, which is wierd
the exact message is : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/OfficialBackend/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
thanks in advance
I also tried suggestion given to me by mah517, I still get a CORS, even though it returns a 200 with the actual message, which is wierd


One thing you have to make sure of is that the 'headers' in your response are the exact same as the 'headers' you have set here in API Gateway.

so in that case, you mean the headers returned by my nodeJS app?

how would I set this up?

Wherever you have the code to return your response, add a 'headers' key; the value should be a dictionary with access control allow headers as one key and access control allow origin as the other. The values of those keys should be the same as what you have in API Gateway, the keys should also be written exactly as they are in API Gateway.

in Nodejs or in reactjs do I put this? could you make a full answer with code example plz so I can accept youranswer if it works

take my "/" path as an example, how would I modify it? : app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.json({ success: true, message: 'Welcome to the backend!' });
});

so the format for your response should be the following:
{
success: true,
message: "Welcome to the backend!",
headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT"
}
}

just tried your solution, still same response unfortunatly, with GETS it returns the message with 200 however which is wierd, but with POST/PUT it returns nothing, CORS in all cases

I added a screenshot of my attempt in the original question

If you have "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, you can't have the wildcard * for Access-Control-Allow-Origin. This rule is enforced by the browser.

tried to remove it, still not working

I've encountered the same issue in the recent times. Just make a small addition in the method response and integration response.I'll be attaching the ss.



Sorry for late response, just back from vacation, where is that window? I don't see it anywhere?

wait nvm found it, it works on some calls now!  still doesn't work for sign-in though

Omg ok I realize now, I have to do this for every endpoint! annoying!

anyway good job, you found the solution!
